# How to define a file path when dealing with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

**This issue has been solved sorry for any time wasted I'm using notepad++ due to hardware constraints so I wasn't aware of needing to import OS to define a filepath**

I am trying to create a TFLite model, I have drawn an arrow to where I'm getting the file path error:

Error: (NameError: name 'oranges' is not defined)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.data_util.image_dataloader import ImageClassifierDataLoader
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task import image_classifier
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task.model_spec import efficientnet_b0_spec
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task.model_spec import ImageModelSpec

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(oranges) <-- oranges is a folder containing the test 
                                                          images. It is in the same folder as this file
model = image_classifier.create(data)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate()

model.export('image_classifier.tflite', 'image_labels.txt')
```

Comment: Had you done any research on that error? Even something like a good IDE would point out the issue...

Comment: I'm using the example on google code lab which used an image path based on googleapi's storage which threw me off.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_customization/demo/image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=KKRaYHABpob5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` must be a folder containing your images for modelling. In this case, the entry `oranges` is not defined as a folder path anywhere in the code.

To create a folder path, run:

```
import os
oranges = os.path.abspath('oranges')
```

Before executing the code:

```
data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(oranges)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't realize we must define the path beforehand.